# When did bash's shopt huponexit start defaulting to off?

Tags: bash, history, nohup

On Monday morning, I logged into a box with `ssh` and ran the following command:

```
tail -f /var/log/foo/bar.log | grep something_interesting &
```

At some point later in the day, I logged out by pressing Ctrl+D.

On Friday, I logged into the same box, and discovered that the `tail` processes were still running. I was expecting them to have quit when I logged out.

Upon digging further, it appears that `shopt huponexit` is set to `off` on that box, and on every other Linux box I've tried, and on the one Mac OS X box I've tried.

When did this start defaulting to `off`, rather than `on`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It defaulted to off when it was introduced, in bash 2.02:

```
@@ -119,6 +123,10 @@ int interactive = 0;
 /* Non-zero means that the shell was started as an interactive shell. */
 int interactive_shell = 0;

+/* Non-zero means to send a SIGHUP to all jobs when an interactive login
+   shell exits. */
+int hup_on_exit = 0;
+
```

http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/commit/shell.c?id=cce855bc5b117cb7ae70064131120687bc69fac0

Comment: Did bash always send HUP before that was introduced? Assuming not using `nohup` I mean.

I ask because I distinctly remember having to use `nohup` all of the time in the past (but the past is SunOS 4.x...)

Comment: @RogerLipscombe I just tested your use case (`tail -f | grep &`) in bash 2.01.1, and the process kept running after closing the shell.  Perhaps the system where you saw different behaviour had something non-standard, such as a system-wide bashrc that enabled it?

Comment: That's entirely possible: I'm talking about a university computer system; ops would probably _not_ want background processes running after logoff accidentally. But we are talking ~20 years ago...