# when to use NOHUP

Tags: nohup

I would like to know the purpose of `nohup` *these days*.

I ask because I read this

> Nohup is short for “No Hangups.” It’s not a command that you run by itself. Nohup is a supplemental command that tells the Linux system not to stop another command once it has started. That means it’ll keep running until it’s done, even if the user that started it logs out. The syntax for nohup is simple and looks something like this:
>
> nohup sh your-script.sh &
>
> Notice the “&” at the end of the command. That moves the command to the background, freeing up the terminal that you’re working in.
>
> Nohup works with just about any command that you run in the terminal. It can be run with custom scripts as well as standard system commands and command line utilities.

With using linux distributions such as SLES 11.4, or RHEL/CentOS 7.x, I can

- remote log in to linux over the network via SSH
- run the simple program below, or any other, doing `./a.out &`
- log out of linux; type exit in the putty SSH terminal
- my sample program below, or any other including bash, csh, or tcsh shell scripts, run to completion just fine without the need for `nohup`
- typing exit in putty to close an SSH session, I would think that qualifies as a logout?

Is there any purpose or value with `nouhup` today?  Is it a kernel >= 3.x thing? For however long I can remember (kernel >= 2.6) I've never used `nohup` and have always just use `&` with no problems.

Can someone give me a practical scenario where `nohup` would be used?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*
    sample C code, to print numbers to a file named zz.tmp
    the numbers 0 to 29 over 30 seconds
*/

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
   FILE *fp;
   int i;

   i = 0;
   fp = fopen("zz.tmp", "w" );

   while ( i < 30 )
   {
      fprintf( fp, "%d\n", i++ );
      sleep( 1 );
   }
   fclose( fp );
   return 0;
}
```

**mysleep.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 1000
```

On Centos 7.7, optiplex pc login with keyboard & mouse, my account is bash. I do `nohup ./mysleep.sh` and then **control-z**.  When typing `jobs` I see `[1]+ Stopped nohup ./mysleep.sh`

A `ps -ef | grep mysleep` shows that process id existing, but if I close the terminal window via X in upper right corner, that process goes away so it seems `nohup` is not working?

Comment: Related - [For which versions of linux does nohup serve a purpose](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/567495/100397)

Comment: the comment there was made: **on all linux/unix system the background jobs will be killed with a HUP signal upon log-out**.  I believe that to be **not true**.

Comment: I can change it to `while < 1000` and `fprintf( stdout, "%d\n", i++ );` and it continues to run; albeit when I log back in it is not printing to the terminal but the program [process] is still running just fine.  I experience this all the time running number crunching codes on linux at work- they write info to the terminal but the valued result ends up in a text file, we do `crunchmynumbers.x > log.txt &` and we do not need to use nohup.

Comment: Related questions are https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/284470/5132 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/492465/5132 .

Comment: @JdeBP except that bash will resend the HUP signal to its jobs, independent of `shopt -s huponexit` or the job control features implemented by the OS. Using `nohup` is NOT only for the case where `huponexit` is set in bash.

Comment: In the words "related", "questions", "are", and "and" you will find no assertions of what the Bourne Again shell does, to take exception to.  (-:

Comment: See another [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/542699/308316) which struggles to explain the diff between the shell-specific job control features and those implemented by the OS

Comment: @JdeBP in case it wasn't clear, both links you pointed to are narrowly about bash's `huponexit` feature, which is NOT on by default.

Answer (score 5):

> remote log in to linux over the network via SSH ... log out of linux; type `exit` in the putty SSH terminal
>
> Can someone give me a practical scenario where `nohup` would be used?

Sure. Assuming your shell is bash (see below why), instead of typing `exit` or `^D`, type `~.` at the beginning of a line, which will cause your ssh client to *disconnect*:

```
$ ssh localhost
ssh$ sleep 3600 &
[1] 5765
ssh$ ~.
ssh$ Connection to localhost closed.
$ ps 5765
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
```

You can use your program instead of `sleep`; and instead of disconnecting via `~.`, you can kill your ssh client or crash the machine it runs on. You want your process to survive this? Use `nohup` ;-)

Breaking the connection will cause the server process which manages its other end to exit, causing the kernel (any Unix/Linux kernel) to tear down the pseudo-terminal ssh had created, and to send a `SIGHUP` signal to the session leader (the bash shell), which according to the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Signals):

> The shell exits by default upon receipt of a `SIGHUP`.   Before  exiting,
>          an  interactive  shell  resends  the  `SIGHUP`  to  all  jobs, running or
>          stopped.  Stopped jobs are sent `SIGCONT` to ensure that they receive the
>          `SIGHUP`.

Many people confuse this **bash feature** with **a)** the regular job control thing implemented by the kernel, which will only send a `SIGCONT`/`SIGHUP` pair to the **stopped**, not to the **running** jobs [1] and **b)** another bash feature (`shopt -s huponexit`) which causes a *login* bash shell to send a `SIGHUP` to its jobs even when exiting normally (eg. via `exit`).

[1] a *stopped* job is a job (= process group) which contains at least one stopped process. A *process* is stopped as an effect of the default action of a signal like `SIGTSTP`, `SIGSTOP`, `SIGTTIN` or `SIGTTOU`. Processes which are "sleeping" on a blocking system call like `read`, `nanosleep`, `select`, etc are not considered stopped, but running.

#### Why `nohup` may not always help

`nohup` just sets the disposition of `SIGHUP` to ignore and does some redirections, it **does not guarantee** that the process will not be killed by other ways.

**a)** If the `nohup ..` job is *stopped*, an interactive bash will also send it a `SIGTERM` signal, not just a `SIGHUP`/`SIGCONT` pair:

> If  an  attempt to exit bash is made while jobs are stopped [...] the shell prints a warning message [...] If a second attempt to exit is made without an intervening command, the shell does not  print  another warning, and any stopped jobs are *terminated*.

[*terminated* = sent a `SIGTERM` signal; this is another ksh/bash feature, not present in all shells]

All this can be worked around by simple tricks like double-forks and by creating a new session with `setsid(1)`, but

**b)** `systemd` may also "clean up" a logged-out session by forcefully killing (with `SIGTERM` followed by `SIGKILL`) any left-over processes if its `KillUserProcesses` setting is on, which is the default in some distros.

Comment: I added to my original question.  I am confused by what you are referring to as a stopped process.  Are you saying a running processes is not affected by a `SIGHUP` therefore `nohup` is not applicable on something like `./a.out &` which is likely to always be running and not be affected by a `SIGHUP`?

Comment: 1. `ps -ef | grep mysleep` is not the right way to check if that process is still running: bash will optimize the last command, `sleep 1000` to `exec sleep 1000` -- which will run the `sleep` in the same process, whose _name_ and _command line_ will no longer include `mysleep` 2. I'm saying exactly the contrary of that: `./a.out &` can be sent a `SIGHUP` if it's started from bash (or some other "advanced" shell which expands the job control implemented by the OS with its own actions).

Comment: @ron fwiw, your stopped `mysleep.sh` will be killed by a `SIGTERM` explicitly sent by bash, not by a `SIGHUP`, so starting it via `nohup` doesn't make any difference. An interactive bash also sends a `SIGTERM` to the stopped jobs, not just a `SIGHUP` + `SIGCONT`.

Comment: @ron I've added a section about why/when nohup may not help; another situation is when it's hup'ed [before](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/481033/308316) being able to ignore the sighup signal. But this is getting way off the original question and turning into a quirks and trivia collection. If the whole point of your Q was to "prove" that nohup is/was always useless and you can simply run `foo &` and log out and `foo` won't be hup'ed, THAT IS WRONG.

Answer (score 0):

I always think of nohup as a sort poor man's daemon.
So do these folks:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958249/whats-the-difference-between-nohup-and-a-daemon

It gets used as a way to code a shell daemon.